# 9 to 10: Word for when the number of digits increases

Tags: single-word-requests, mathematics

Is there a word that describes when a number increases in number of digits?

Example:

- 9 to 10 (one, then two digits)
- 99 to 100 (two, then three digits)
- 999 to 1000 (three, then four digits)

Use Case:

I would like to succinctly and/or mathematically describe what's happening in a problem I have here: [Sequential IDs with field calculator: Pad a prefixed field to specific length](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/252913/sequential-ids-with-field-calculator-pad-a-prefixed-field-to-specific-length)

Comment: Its *order of magnitude* increases.

Comment: @DanBron - Not sure you're right; at the very least using that term here is confusing. 0.999m is three orders of magnitude bigger than 1mm, not two.

Comment: Are you referring solely to counting numbers expressed minimally? 007 is a (slightly less common) rewrite of 7, and 0.90 has three places shown of which one or two may be necessary (though it's usual not to suppress the units numeral here).

Comment: You linked to something very long.  Could you just post a sample sentence, please?  // What about *carrying*?  When you add 3 + 4, there is no need to carry.  When you add 9 + 1, you write 0 and carry the 1. // Possibly roll over -- as happens with an odometer.

Comment: The ***characteristic of the  number’s (base 10) logarithm*** has been incremented.

Comment: @Andy… leave Dan alone. He was basically defining magnitude.

Part of which means 0.999m is no orders of magnitude bigger than 1mm nor can they be compared, in that way. You changed the base, not the magnitude.

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin - Not sure why I decided to change the units in my example. But, as an engineer, 999mm and 1000mm are the same order of magnitude. DanBron's comment might work with [Wikipedia's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_magnitude) opening definition, but it doesn't tally with the "Uses" section: "*If numbers differ by one order of magnitude, x is about ten times different in quantity than y.*" Hence my "at the very least, using that term here is confusing".

Comment: I misunderstood. We’re talking only *about numbers of digits*, not *numeric value*.
I don’t remember a term for that and neither British nor US on-line kiddy-school primers said anything but, eg, *X-digit numbers*.
Your term would revolve around *place order* or *length* and if as in that GIS link it’s for a databases text field, perhaps *word length* or *len*.
As Jim notes that’s about content, not process.
Python, VBScript, etc won’t be too flexible but in English, why not make up a term?
If a *real* phrase turns up, you can always switch.

Comment: @AndyT: In your example, "order of magnitude" refers to the **units** that are being used, not the numerical value. And when you refer to _"If numbers differ by one order of magnitude, x is about ten times different in quantity than y."_, then you must also observe that this statement is made under the assumption of _ceteris paribus_, i.e. assuming the same base number. E.g. (3,30,300,3000) are each one order of magnitude greater than their predecessor (in **this** case, also each other's tenfold). But so are (1,20,300,4000) or (9,10,999,1000) even though they don't use the same base value.

Comment: @Flater - No. My comment still stands. I agree that 300 is one order of magnitude larger than 20, but as far as usage within the field of civil engineering goes 1000 is not one order of magnitude larger than 999. "Order of magnitude" is on a logarithmic scale, and hence if one order of magnitude is 10, half an order of magnitude is the square root of 10, 3.16. But we don't ever talk in terms of fractional orders. Hence "one order of magnitude" means "anything from 3.16 times larger to 31.6 times larger". 300 is 15 times larger than 20; 3.16<15<31.6 - one order of magnitude. 1000/999 << 3.16!

Comment: @AndyT: You're right about the logarithmic scale, but you must then also **use scientific notation**. 999 = **9.99 * 10²** and 1000 = **1.00 * 10³**. 10³ is one order of magnitude greater than 10². I'm not following your argument for "half an order of magnitude", I was not suggesting we use fractions to describe the order of magnitude.

Comment: @Flater - As we don't use fractions of orders of magnitude, anything that is 0.5 orders of magnitude to 1.5 orders of magnitude gets called "one order of magnitude". Hence why 300 is an order of magnitude greater than 20, despite not being exactly 10 times greater. It is not because it has a "number length" of three vs a "number length" of two, it is because it is between 3.16 and 31.6 times greater. If I have two bits of wood, one is 999mm long and the other is 1001mm long, I would say "their length is the same order of magnitude", meaning "their length is approximately the same".

Comment: @AndyT: Every example you've used that includes units of measurement, makes it ambiguous as to whether "orders of magnitude" refers to the units of measurement or the **values**. When observing the values alone (without any unit of measurements), then 1001 is an order of magnitude greater than 999. Note that when you say _"A is an order of magnitude greater than B"_, you are saying _"the order of magnitude of A is one greater than the order of magnitude of B"_. The statement compares **orders of magnitude**, it does not compare **the values themselves**.

Comment: @AndyT: Similarly, _"Tom is one paygrade up from Bob"_ compares Tom and Bob's **paygrades**, it does not compare Tom and Bob themselves.

Comment: @Flater - Right, I now understand what you are saying, my apologies for being slow. [Please note I mean that genuinely, not sarcastically.] I responded to that argument back on the 8th September. Perhaps my response needs rewording for clarity? How about: There are two uses of "order of magnitude": the "base" definition (by which 1001 is an order of magnitude higher than 999), and the "about 10 times" definition (by which 1001 is the same order as 999). In my profession the latter definition is used, hence I find the suggestion to use "order of magnitude" in this situation to be confusing.

Comment: @AndyT: I find the second usage to be incorrect (or maybe "imprecise" is a better word to use here). An order of magnitude is strictly defined in mathematics. The second usage seems figurative and does not focus on exact values (similar to something being described as "lightyears ahead", when in reality you're not measuring distance, let alone _precise_ distance)

Comment: @Flater and AndyT : Does someone want to post an educated answer about **order of magnitude**?

Comment: I cursorily speed read all these comments by all you math whizzes (that's my assumption), but isn't this: tens, hundreds and thousands? The number of digits changes when you pass over a threshold whereby one more digit makes the number go from single digits to  tens; tens to hundreds and hundreds to thousands.

Comment: just a point; the number of digits is usually proportional to the size of the number - in fact we have n.o.d. = floor ( log_10 N ) in base 10

Answer (score 1):

It is a number system dependent feature - for example [Roman numerals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roman_numerals) do this all the time. If you are using a positional number system, you could say the number of digits **jumps**.

Answer (score 0):

Number Length ([Wolfram](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/NumberLength.html))

> The length of a number n in base b is the number of digits in the base-b numeral for n

Comment: Number length may describe what’s being measured.  It does not describe the event of it increasing by one.

Comment: @Jim: Correct, but once you understand the meaning of "number length", it's trivial to then use it in a sentence, e.g. "the number length increases by 1". However, I do agree that an example sentence would improve the quality of the answer.

Comment: As a total innumerate, I have to say that sounds baffling. I thought there were many bases, so we're talking about something like Pi that go out indefinitely?